# PHP как обращается php к ключу массива

Tags: php

При обращение к ключу массива php ОБХОДИТ массив и ищет нужный ключ и соответственно значение или это процесс происходит как с переменными так сказать напрямую?

Я все это к тому, что если есть огромный массив и я хочу обращаться по ключу несколько раз:

```
if($my_arr['key'] === 'someValue') {
    ...
} elseif ($my_arr['key'] === 'someValue') {
    ...
} elseif ($my_arr['key'] === 'someValue') {
    ...
} и т.д.
```

или нужно создать переменную и присвоить ей значение ключа?

```
$val = $my_arr['key'];
if($val === 'someValue') {
    ...
} elseif ($val === 'someValue') {
    ...
} elseif ($val === 'someValue') {
    ...
} и т.д.
```

Все зависит от того, постоянно заново ищется значение или нет?
Подскажите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если коротко: Нет. Не обходит

Если подробно: Ключи ассоциативных массивов в любых языках хранятся в виде дерева. Причем хранятся не сами ключи, а их хеши. При обращении к элементу по ключу происходит вычисление хеша и бинарный поиск по дереву ключей. В результате получается указатель на конкреный элемент массива, с последующей выборкой значения. Причем, насколько я понимаю, в интерпретируемых языках доступ к переменным происходит по такому принципу. То есть переменную `variable` интерпретатор вызывает как `scope["variable"]`.

Дополнительно можно почитать в [статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/162685/)